# How to run "sbt run" without compilation/checks?

Tags: scala, sbt, udash

VPS has low memory and cannot run compilation without crashing. I cannot generate working fat-jar (tried a lot of stuff with sbt-assembly, sbt-native-packager and sbt-start-script without any success).

I am not asking how to create a fat-jar.

Question:
**How to prepare** (I guess just compile it on other machine) **and how to "sbt run" without triggering dependency checks and compilation?**

Answer (score 1):

Is there a possibility to build the JAR outside of the server and just push the JAR over? If this is your production server of some sort, you don't want to include compiler dependent libraries on the server.

May be try:

```
offline := true
```

Or perhaps,

```
cleanKeepFiles ++= Seq("resolution-cache", "streams").map(target.value / _)
```

Which should sort of avoid doing the resolution check!